# How do I navigate to local/intranet locations using WebView?

Tags: c#, xaml, webview, uwp

I'm a coding newbie starting to learn how to build UWP apps with C# and XAML. I'm working on creating an app that uses WebView to access a device on my network via its IP address. However, WebView is unable to connect to intranet locations like IP address or .local domains, but normal websites work fine.

I did some research and found [this](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/issues/2226), where someone had the same issue and fixed it by setting IsPrivateNetworkClientServerCapabilityEnabled to true. However, when I add it, I get an error saying that the property was not found in type 'WebView'.

I have checked my NuGet packages, and I have Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls installed and up-to-date.
The code-behind page has using directives for all of the XAML namespaces and Windows Community Toolkit.
Here's my code:

```
    <Grid>
        <WebView Source="http://192.168.4.40"
                 IsPrivateNetworkClientServerCapabilityEnabled="True"/>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are different from the Github issue. It's a WPF app and it's using NuGet package-Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32.UI.Controls. Your app is a UWP app and you could just use the native WebView Control without installing Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.

For your scenario, please add the following capabilities in the manifest file:

1. Private Networks (Client & Server)
2. Internet (Client & Server)
3. Enterprise Authentication

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. However, even after enabling those three capabilities, the problem persists. Is there anything else I should do besides toggling them in the manifest?

Comment: Are you able to access the site using a browser?

Comment: Yes. This sentence is just to meet the minimum comment length.

Comment: Using Edge, right? Because webivew is using Edge's core.

Comment: Yes. This sentence is also to meet the minimum comment length.

Comment: I‘ve asked other engineers to take a look at this issue. Thank you for your patience in advance.

Comment: Our team wants to know more about your issue because we can't reproduce this. If your issue still exists, could you please share the network trace? Please replace all the sensitive information in the network trace with something like <OMMITTED FOR PRIVACY>.  If would be better if you can use an Http site to test with instead of https because the network trace will be more readable. Can you reproduce the issue with intranet and local hosting, with the above options, on a personal network that’s not managed by IT or restrictive group policies/firewall rules?

Comment: So I tried using a different IP address (for a different device) and it worked. There must be an issue with the specific IP address I'm trying to connect to. My apologies for not trying this earlier